# django jQuery AJAX Autocomplete

Tags: django, autocomplete

I set an autocomplete field like bellow but its not working :(
Is there any problem in it?

import jQuery and jQuery UI:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'   %}">
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.min.js' %}">
 </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/jquery-ui.css' %}">
```

In html template:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="places">Places: </label>
<input id="places">
</div>
```

and :

```
<script>

$(function() {
$("#places").autocomplete({
  source: "/api/get_places/",
  select: function (event, ui) { //item selected
    AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
  },
  minLength: 2,
 });
 });

 function AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
  {
  var selectedObj = ui.item;
 }

</script>
```

In url.py :

```
url(r'^api/get_places/', views.get_places, name='get_places'),
```

in views.py :

```
def get_places(request):
if request.is_ajax():
  q = request.GET.get('term', '')
  places = Place.objects.filter(city__icontains=q)
  results = []
  for pl in places:
    place_json = {}
    place_json = pl.city + "," + pl.state
    results.append(place_json)
 data = json.dumps(results)
else:
  data = 'fail'
mimetype = 'application/json'
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

when i add print(results) in view, it returns correct fields from database based on the letter i entered in the textbox .
so the problem is in the sending and receiving json data which it return!

the problem should be here and no code like print('hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh') can be executed after it :

```
    data = json.dumps(results)
```

error in page http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get_places/:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected keyword at line 1 column 1 of the JSON    data
```

Answer (score 0):

change code like this

```
def get_places(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')
        places = Place.objects.filter(city__icontains=q)
        results = []
        for pl in places:
           place_json = {}
           place_json['label'] = p1.state
           results.append(place_json)
       data = json.dumps(results)
     else:
       data = 'fail'
     mimetype = 'application/json'
     return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

create python list of dictionaries before dumps in to JSON

JQuery autocomplete key name should be 'label' by default, it shows in the autocomplete list

check it out..

Comment: same error on   `api/get_places/: ` page and non of the print command after  `data = json.dumps(results) ` execute